# WTFx1000 The ERC-20 Token Transfer might have Failed (ErrCode: unable to locate corresponding Transfer event log), check with sender

Tags: transactions, tokens, error

im sending from one mew to another mew
my gas is doubled 
why do i keep getting this
TxHash: 0xac2bdee062f62ede0a478ea6a60e4c4465d76f099e3764895b849c491baa5f75 TxReceipt Status:FailBlock Height:4941786 (129 block confirmations)
TimeStamp:34 mins ago (Jan-20-2018 05:28:05 PM +UTC)
From:0xe1201a1cdd447c684f435313bf27554fc628c3d3
To:Contract 0x0b76544f6c413a555f309bf76260d1e02377c02a (InternetNodeToken)

**The ERC-20 Token Transfer might have Failed (ErrCode: unable to locate corresponding Transfer event log), check with sender.Value: 0 Ether ($0.00) Gas Limit: 250000

please help

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the token contract. It has this:

```
require (balanceOf[_from] > _value);
```

which means you can never send all your tokens. You tried to send 97.288000 tokens, which is your complete balance. Try 97.287999 instead. This token uses 6 decimal places, so that's the maximum you'll be able to send.